# How to read file in C# but only between two strings

Tags: c#

I want to read .ps1 file in C#. .PS1 file have a few methods and I want to read only one method. Can anyone help me how to do that? 
I want to read between #### characters and all text put in list.
Thank you!

```
########
Configuration LogOff
{
Script LogOffUsers
  {
  }
}
########
Configuration StopServices
{
 Script LogOffUsers
   {
   }
}
########
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and we might be able to help you figure out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `string.Split` function is what you are looking for.

```
string fileText = ReadConfigurationFileAsText();
string[] configurations = fileText.Split("########");
```

The `configurations` array will contain all configurations separated by "########".

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do what you pretend:

```
string line, finalText = string.Empty;  
bool fileBetweenTags;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");  
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
    if (line == "########"){
        fileBetweenTags = !fileBetweenTags;
    }
    if(fileBetweenTags){
        finalText += line; //or wtv code you want here
    }
}  

file.Close();
```